# Python: How to export Sympy image to png?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, sympy

Python: How to export Sympy image to png?

Who has any idea with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `saveimage` method:

```
import sympy
x, y, z = sympy.symbols('xyz')
p = sympy.Plot(x * y ** 3 - y * x ** 3)
p.saveimage('/tmp/plot.png', format='png')
```

Comment: Can we save to a buffer or a memory object?