# How to export Sympy equation to an image

Tags: python, sympy

I would like to export an equation to a PNG image so, for example:

```
from math import pi, sin

from sympy import init_printing, diff, var, solve
from sympy import sin as sympy_sin
init_printing()

g_v, beta, gamma_a, gamma_b, gamma_c = var("g_v beta gamma_a gamma_b gamma_c")
a, b, c  = var(" a b c")

eq = g_v*sympy_sin(beta)*a*b*c + 2*gamma_a*b*c + 2*gamma_b*a*c + 2*gamma_c*a*b

deq_da = diff(eq, a)
deq_db = diff(eq, b)
deq_dc = diff(eq, c)

solution = solve([deq_da,deq_db,deq_dc],[a,b,c])[1]
solution
```

I would like to export solution to a PNG image. Like the one below:

[image]

There are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964968/python-how-to-export-sympy-image-to-png) [other](https://groups.google.com/g/sympy/c/_zF-tNdbnCY) [places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818279/render-equation-to-png-file-using-python) [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68465875/saving-an-image-of-an-expression-displayed-with-sympy) *kind of* address this question. But, they are all unclear, or obsolete. I think the Sympy community would benefit from having a clear best-practice answer to this question.

Comment: This [solution using a matplotlib image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31371907/1804173) (and converting the sympy expression into LaTeX) could be an option as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is somewhat obscure but SymPy's `preview` function can do this:

```py
with open('solution.png', 'wb') as outputfile:
    preview(solution, viewer='BytesIO', outputbuffer=outputfile)
```

Behind the scenes this uses LaTeX so you'll need to have that installed and on PATH (specifically it uses `latex` and `dvipng` by default).

It would be a reasonable feature request to make the above achievable with something more straight-forward like `saveimage(solution, 'solution.png')`.